# ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 49:0-53:205 Can't reexport the named export

Tags: typescript, webpack, graphql, webpack-4

I try to build the `typescript` based app as `graphql` server using `webpack 4`.

but get errors like:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 49:0-53:205
Can't reexport the named export 'BREAK' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./graphql/schema.ts
 @ ./graphql/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 64:0-98:42
Can't reexport the named export 'BreakingChangeType' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./graphql/schema.ts
 @ ./graphql/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 36:0-47:50
Can't reexport the named export 'DEFAULT_DEPRECATION_REASON' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./graphql/schema.ts
 @ ./graphql/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 64:0-98:42
Can't reexport the named export 'DangerousChangeType' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./graphql/schema.ts
 @ ./graphql/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 49:0-53:205
Can't reexport the named export 'DirectiveLocation' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./graphql/schema.ts
 @ ./graphql/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/graphql/index.mjs 58:0-60:675
Can't reexport the named export 'FieldsOnCorrectTypeRule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./graphql/schema.ts
 @ ./graphql/server.ts
.....
```

Comment: I seem to have the same problem using Apollo Angular in SSR mode. Did you manage to solve it @Edgaras Karka?

Answer (score 0):

I was running exactly the same issue today when using Angular Universal SSR.

My solution was to include this line to the `externals` object in my webpack config file.

```
externals: {
  './dist/server/main': 'require("./server/main")'
},
```

For those running into the same problem when using Angular 8 and Apollo for Graphql, this is the migration guide that threw some light in my soul: [Angular Universal v8 upgrade guide](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/v8-upgrade-guide.md)